# eBPF, track values longer than stack size?

Tags: c, bpf, ebpf

I'm extending a program which take arguments of traced function and print it. Everything works fine with numeric arguments and short strings. But it's not clear how to handle with long string that longer than stack size in eBPF (which is limited with 512 byte).

In example below, string is limited by 80 bytes, of course it can be increased up to 512, but how to track more longer strings?

Example of C program with traced function which called "ameba"

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

char * ameba(char * s1);

int main(void) {
    printf("%s\n", ameba("verylonglongstring...1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111"));
}

char * ameba(char * s1) {
    char *s;
    s = (char *) malloc(128);
    sleep(1);
    snprintf(s, 128, "ameba: %s", s1);
    return s;
}
```

Example of Go code

```
package main

import "C"
import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/binary"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "os/signal"
    "unsafe"

    bpf "github.com/iovisor/gobpf/bcc"
)

const source string = `
#include <uapi/linux/ptrace.h>
#include <linux/sched.h>

struct ameba_event_t {
        u32 pid;
        char comm[TASK_COMM_LEN];
        char arg1[80];
} __attribute__((packed));

BPF_PERF_OUTPUT(ameba_events);

int get_input_args(struct pt_regs *ctx) {
        struct ameba_event_t event = {};
        if (!PT_REGS_PARM1(ctx))
                return 0;
        event.pid = bpf_get_current_pid_tgid();
        bpf_get_current_comm(&event.comm, sizeof(event.comm));
        bpf_probe_read(&event.arg1, sizeof(event.arg1), (void *)PT_REGS_PARM1(ctx));
        ameba_events.perf_submit(ctx, &event, sizeof(event));

        return 0;
}
`

type amebaEvent struct {
    Pid uint32
    Comm [16]byte
    Arg1 [80]byte
}

func main() {
    m := bpf.NewModule(source, []string{})
    defer m.Close()

    amebaUprobe, err := m.LoadUprobe("get_input_args")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "Failed to load get_input_args: %s\n", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    err = m.AttachUprobe("/home/lesovsky/Git/sandbox/ameba", "ameba", amebaUprobe, -1)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "Failed to attach input_args: %s\n", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    table := bpf.NewTable(m.TableId("ameba_events"), m)

    channel := make(chan []byte)

    perfMap, err := bpf.InitPerfMap(table, channel)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "Failed to init perf map: %s\n", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    sig := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    signal.Notify(sig, os.Interrupt, os.Kill)

    fmt.Printf("%10s\t%s\t%s\n", "PID", "COMMAND", "ARG1")
    go func() {
        var event amebaEvent
        for {
            data := <-channel
            err := binary.Read(bytes.NewBuffer(data), binary.LittleEndian, &event)
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Printf("failed to decode received data: %s\n", err)
                continue
            }

            comm := (*C.char)(unsafe.Pointer(&event.Comm))
            query := (*C.char)(unsafe.Pointer(&event.Query))
            fmt.Printf("%10d\t%s\t%s\n", event.Pid, C.GoString(comm), C.GoString(query))
        }
    }()

    perfMap.Start()
    <-sig
    perfMap.Stop()
}
```

I read about BPF_MAP_TYPE_PERCPU_ARRAY could help in such case, but it's not clear for me how to use it.

EDIT: Go program has been modified to using "C" and "unsafe".

Comment: Literal strings aren't passed or stored on the stack. What is being passed to your `ameba` function is a *pointer* to the first character of the long string. It then returns a *pointer* to the first element of data allocated on the heap. The only thing stored on the stack (traditionally) is the pointer variables themselves, not the data they point to.

Comment: You have a memory leak though.

Comment: `s = (char *) malloc(128);` just allocate more memory... `s = malloc(strlen(s1) + 1);`

Comment: Maybe I explained wrong, in general I trying to save pointer into ameba_event_t struct in BPF program and dereference it in go program. Currently it's done through Arg1 variable which is limited by 80 bytes.

(Memory leak and over-allocation are not the things about which I'm worrying here and now)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I read about BPF_MAP_TYPE_PERCPU_ARRAY could help in such case, but it's not clear for me how to use it.

You're right. Peeps usually rely on per-cpu arrays to overcome stack size limitations. The following implements that sort of solution, whereby I'm using a per-cpu array to store `struct ameba_event_t` instead of storing it on the stack.

I think you're going to need Linux v4.18 to be able to do this (you need commit [d71962f](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=d71962f3e627b5941804036755c844fabfb65ff5)). I haven't tested the code as I don't have the right setup at hand, but can later if you run into any issue.

```
#include <uapi/linux/ptrace.h>
#include <linux/sched.h>

struct ameba_event_t {
    u32 pid;
    char comm[TASK_COMM_LEN];
    char arg1[512];
} __attribute__((packed));

BPF_PERF_OUTPUT(ameba_events);
BPF_PERCPU_ARRAY(ameba_struct, struct ameba_event_t, 1);

int get_input_args(struct pt_regs *ctx) {
    int zero = 0;
    if (!PT_REGS_PARM1(ctx))
        return 0;
    struct ameba_event_t* event = ameba_struct.lookup(&zero);
    if (!event)
        return 0;
    event->pid = bpf_get_current_pid_tgid();
    bpf_get_current_comm(&event->comm, sizeof(event->comm));
    bpf_probe_read(&event->arg1, sizeof(event->arg1), (void *)PT_REGS_PARM1(ctx));
    ameba_events.perf_submit(ctx, event, sizeof(*event));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I booted into 4.18 kernel and implement your solution, but long args are still truncated to arg1 limitation to 80 bytes. I think I need a way to replace arg1[80] to something that have no such limitation. But I checked a lot of "bcc" tools and everywhere used variables with fixed length.

Comment: Anyway it's impossible to guess what length of the string will be passed in traced function. So it's reasonable to set appropriate limit and discard too long strings.
Thank you.

Comment: That's right, you have to set a fixed length for `struct ameba_event_t`. You can set `arg1` to a very large size though. Not sure about the performance impact of using a very large `arg1`.

Comment: What size would be normal? 8Kb is it ok?

Comment: That's not something I can answer for you. If you know most strings you want to capture are less than 8Kb and you've checked that any overhead it creates is acceptable for you, then sure!